# How can I implement Logic App HTTP Connector paging

Tags: http, azure-logic-apps

According to Microsoft documentation paging is handled for you, per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exceed-default-page-size-with-pagination); however, I find despite setting a threshold (of 3000 records), I only get back 1000, suggesting I'm hitting another limit

I've also tried implementing paging "manually", as in [Graph Pagination in Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838128/graph-pagination-in-logic-apps)
, but I don't even see odata.nextLink in the result set (although I can see it in Graph Explorer)

Confused! Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can partially answer my own question here: odata.nextLink is only supplied if Pagination is Off, which makes sense

But I'd still like to know why when it's on, I get fewer records than the Threshold I set, although I know there are more ...

Update: a later attempt got over this problem, and I'm now getting >1000 rows back OK. It would be nice to know why it didn't work earlier; otherwise consider question answered